# WebSphere Message Broker: Simple Flow Error

Tags: websphere, message, messagebroker

I'm creating a simple MessageBroker flow.  It goes MQInput Node -> Compute -> MQOutput Node where all Compute does is:

CALL CopyEntireMessage();
SET OutputRoot.Properties.MessageFormat='XML1';

It should only change the message format from Binary1 to XML1.  However, the MQOutput Node fails and sends the message along its Failure connection.  I'm unclear as to the reasons a MQOutput node could fail?

Comment: Could you paste the error message please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the following points:

1. Check the parsing options of compute node in the flow (properties--advanced)
2. Specify the Message set name in the esql.
3. Specify the output queue name (reply to) in the esql.
4. check input and output queues are present in the MQ
5. Check if the function you are calling is there in the esql.

It would be  easier to help if you can provide me the failure message.